# Splitting a value from postcode within sql to group and results

Tags: php, sql, split, substring

I am having some issues with this part of my query, hopefully someone can advise me, Currently i have the postcodes grouping as a complete postalcode but i would like to split this value, and group by the first part of postcode

Perhaps I am overlooking the simple solution to this?

Here is my current query

```
select *, count(jobline_pickup_add_postalcode) as totals
FROM rhrj_jobline
WHERE jobline_date >= '$start' AND jobline_date <= '$end'
GROUP BY jobline_pickup_add_postalcode
```

Any advice would be awesome

EDIT:

My postcodes look like this

```
KA12 0RA - 1 
KA15 1JG - 26 
KA15 2AT - 1 
KA15 2LF - 1 
KA151JG/PA2 6LA - 2
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a database tag.

Comment: You have a substring tag in the question.  Hint, hint.

Comment: So you know what you need to do so read the manual and work out the syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT that are not arguments to a set function.

Comment: Knowing what the post codes you are storing look like _would allow someone to do it all for you_

Comment: the postcodes are typicall ** *** split by space in the value

Comment: ___first part of the postcode___ So is that from start for X chars or from start until SOME CHARACTER OCCURS????????

Comment: Dear Paul. Please remember postcodes are different in different parts of the world! Also remember this is a world wide site! So we need to know EXACTLY what shape and size YOUR postcodes are, and ___which bit___ you want to use

Comment: apologies, G69 7RQ would be a typical value inside the jobline_pickup_add_postalcode field , thanks

Comment: I just want the first part before the space

Comment: So read this [page in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` which follows it on that page

Answer (score 0):

select SUBSTRING_INDEX(jobline_pickup_add_postalcode, ' ', 1) AS papc, count(jobline_pickup_add_postalcode) as totals FROM rhrj_jobline WHERE jobline_date >= '$start' AND jobline_date <= '$end' GROUP BY papc